# Corona - "bad argument #-2 to 'insert'"

Tags: lua, coronasdk

[There](http://www.coronalabs.com/blog/2012/05/01/tutorial-property-callbacks/) is a great tutorial how to wrap the `DisplayObject` in the “proxy”  - it is necessary since due its native background the `DisplayObject` cannot be “inherited”. It all works just fine, but whatever I tried I am still getting an error

```
bad argument #-2 to 'insert'
```

When I try to insert the created object into `DisplayGroup`:

```
self.view:insert(fish)
```

Can anyone help there? After several hour of experiments I am off.

Answer (score 1):

if i'm not mistaken  you are trying to insert a word/string to a display group or maybe the group that you are inserting does not exist  have you try to insert group just like this

```
group:insert(fish)
```

instead of this

```
self.view:insert(fish)
```

if you did try refer to this [link](https://www.google.com.ph/search?q=bad%20argument%20#-2%20to%20%27insert%27%20corona&rlz=1C1CHMO_tlPH525PH525&oq=bad%20argument%20#-2%20to%20%27insert%27%20corona&aqs=chrome.0.69i57j69i60j69i62l2.1583j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Answer (score 0):

Look for the display group name. If you are using storyboard then:

```
function scene:createScene( event )
    -- The display group is named "group" or any name you want
    local group = self.view

    local fish = display.newText("Fish!", 0, 0, native.systemFont, 16)

    -- insert your string or image to the display group
    group:insert(fish)
end
```